# Image Upload & Editing Suddenly not Working

Tags: assets

I'm getting an error on Image Upload and Asset Editing on an existing site. I'm getting the `Upload failed. The error message was: “The file “.../storage/runtime/temp/...” does not appear to be an image.”` error that's been discussed previously here. Imagick version 3.4.3 (ImageMagick 6.7.8-9) *is* installed. Switching the file, the format, or reuploading a previously uploaded image also does not work. Editing old assets w/n Craft yields a generic image icon.

No recent changes to the server that Im aware of. PHP 7.0.33. Craft Pro 3.3.1 ('Im stuck in the upgrade process -- see my other question previously).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue. For some reason Media Temple had switched the PHP implementation from FPM served by NGINX to FPM served by Apache. Switching back to NGINX (or Fast CGI) fixed the issue. I know this issue has come up for others, so a true fix would be great for future reference....